# Exchange 2010 not receiving some emails

Tags: smtp, exchange-2010

Exchange 2010 not receiving emails from some senders. They receive the following email rejection message:

Diagnostic information for administrators:
Generating server: mail.domain.com.au
user@otherdomain.com.au #< #4.4.7> #SMTP#

I enabled protocol logging on the receive connector. I cannot see any errors, however the problem emails appear to get cut short with "250 CHUNKING" being the last log entry (no DATA log entry).

```
2014-10-03T05:09:45.554Z,MAIL\Receive Connector,08D1ACCDF829605D,0,192.168.0.4:25,123.456.789.123:44347,+,,
2014-10-03T05:09:45.554Z,MAIL\Receive Connector,08D1ACCDF829605D,1,192.168.0.4:25,123.456.789.123:44347,*,SMTPSubmit SMTPAcceptAnySender SMTPAcceptAuthoritativeDomainSender AcceptRoutingHeaders,Set Session Permissions
2014-10-03T05:09:45.555Z,MAIL\Receive Connector,08D1ACCDF829605D,2,192.168.0.4:25,123.456.789.123:44347,>,"220 mail.otherdomain.com.au Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Fri, 3 Oct 2014 15:09:45 +1000",
2014-10-03T05:09:45.574Z,MAIL\Receive Connector,08D1ACCDF829605D,3,192.168.0.4:25,123.456.789.123:44347,<,EHLO mail.domain.com.au,
2014-10-03T05:09:45.574Z,MAIL\Receive Connectorl,08D1ACCDF829605D,4,192.168.0.4:25,123.456.789.123:44347,>,250-mail.otherdomain.com.au Hello [123.456.789.123],
2014-10-03T05:09:45.575Z,MAIL\Receive Connector,08D1ACCDF829605D,5,192.168.0.4:25,123.456.789.123:44347,>,250-SIZE 10485760,
2014-10-03T05:09:45.575Z,MAIL\Receive Connector,08D1ACCDF829605D,6,192.168.0.4:25,123.456.789.123:44347,>,250-PIPELINING,
2014-10-03T05:09:45.575Z,MAIL\Receive Connector,08D1ACCDF829605D,7,192.168.0.4:25,123.456.789.123:44347,>,250-DSN,
2014-10-03T05:09:45.575Z,MAIL\Receive Connector,08D1ACCDF829605D,8,192.168.0.4:25,123.456.789.123:44347,>,250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES,
2014-10-03T05:09:45.575Z,MAIL\Receive Connector,08D1ACCDF829605D,9,192.168.0.4:25,123.456.789.123:44347,>,250-STARTTLS,
2014-10-03T05:09:45.575Z,MAIL\Receive Connector,08D1ACCDF829605D,10,192.168.0.4:25,123.456.789.123:44347,>,250-AUTH,
2014-10-03T05:09:45.575Z,MAIL\Receive Connector,08D1ACCDF829605D,11,192.168.0.4:25,123.456.789.123:44347,>,250-8BITMIME,
2014-10-03T05:09:45.575Z,MAIL\Receive Connector,08D1ACCDF829605D,12,192.168.0.4:25,123.456.789.123:44347,>,250-BINARYMIME,
2014-10-03T05:09:45.575Z,MAIL\Receive Connector,08D1ACCDF829605D,13,192.168.0.4:25,123.456.789.123:44347,>,250 CHUNKING,
```

Telnet test to port 25 from the sending mail server loses connection.

[image: telnet port 25 connection to host lost]

Comment: I suspect you're not going to be able to solve this w/o a packet capture of a real conversation between the sending mail server and your receiving server. Is that something you can get and update the question?

Comment: I literally just resolved this issue by moving the inbound SMTP over to a different internet connection, plus setting a reverse DNS with the ISP.

Comment: @Ash Would you please write it as an answer and then mark it as one, so your question won't appear as 'unanswered'?

Answer (score 0):

I literally just resolved this issue by moving the inbound SMTP over to a different internet connection, plus setting a reverse DNS with the ISP.